# Общее и различное в Servlet API и web-socket API

Tags: java, servlet, websocket

Как я понимаю что `Servlet API`, что `web-socket API`, внутри построены на обычных сокетах(Поправте если я не прав). Но реализация `Servlet API` построена на идеологии `request-response`. А `web-socket API` не зависит от подобных схем.

Так как с `Servlet API` я знаком а с websocket нет то пытаюсь найти аналогии в их работе. Помогите разобраться в общей схеме работы "с высоты птичьего полета" как работают вэб-сокеты, сравнительно с сервлетами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WebSocket** использует иной принцип - пересылка сообщений. Сообщения могут быть текстовые или бинарные.

Протокол **WebSocket** начинается с **рукопожатия**, по завершении которого создаётся объект описывающий соединение - **Session**.  После получения это объекта в нем можно зарегистрировать обработчик сообщений.

Вы описываете обработчик сообщения и он будет вызываться при получении сообщения.

Comment: а что касается понятий сессии не могли бы чуть чуть раскрыть а то сессия которая возникает при использовании WebSocket и Servlet это совсем разные вещи?

Comment: @Pavel и да и нет. Сессия в http - это надстройка в некотором роде. А websocket это часть протокола TCP поверх которого он работает.

Comment: Это можно понимать так что вэб-сокет сессия входит в http сессию. Или по другому http сессия включает в себя вэб-сокет сессию. Тоесть декоратор?

Comment: Это совершенно разные сессии.